# How do i create a simple subscription form using html and css, to sit above the footer?

Tags: html, css, forms

How can i create a simple subscription form? i have tried using this codes and css style, but they don't align the way it should be. whats wrong with what i've done? can someone point me in the right direction?
i want the form to have a background color or image and sit just above the footer, how do i achieve this?

```css
.subscribe-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.subscribe-container li {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="subscribe-form" action="#">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <ul class="subscribe-container">
        <li class="subscribe-feature">
          <label for="email">Get Updates</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
      <ul class="subscribe-container">
        <li class="subscribe-feature">
          <input type="text" class="updates" id="updates" placeholder="Email Address">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <ul class="subscribe-container">
        <li class="subscribe-features">
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
      <ul class="subscribe-container">
        <li class="subscribe-features">
          <input type="submit" class="subscribe-btn" value="Subscribe">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: do you use some css framework like bootstrap?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @Sfili_81, I am still new to web design and code writing, so i guess i use it without knowing or not. Thanks for asking

Comment: @Ava my expected output is a very simple for with only  the email address field and a subscribe button with an image in the in the background. thanks fir asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to define the height and width of your class: subscribe-form and then set the background-color or image, like this:

```
.subscribe-form{
        width: 500px;
        heigth: 500px;
        background-image:url("/your directory");
        //or
        background-color: blue;
     }
```

In relation to the form you are going to the right direction, your "action" needs to ref some action page like in php, and if you need something like a javascript function, you can create a tag **script** in your code to enable javascript functions, you will need to add a button type="submit" in your html to call them, like that:

```
    <html>
    <form method="post" class="subscribe-form" action="#" onsubmit="doSomething()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <ul class="subscribe-container">
            <li class="subscribe-feature">
              <label for="email">Get Updates</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <ul class="subscribe-container">
            <li class="subscribe-feature">
              <input type="text" class="updates" id="updates" placeholder="Email Address">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <ul class="subscribe-container">
            <li class="subscribe-features">
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <ul class="subscribe-container">
            <li class="subscribe-features">
              <input type="submit" class="subscribe-btn" value="Subscribe">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Action form</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </html>
<script>
    doSomething() {
        window.alert('Thats the action of my form!');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @Igoohd, Thanks for breaking things down, i will let you know if this works for me, i appreciate!